# What are the properties of divisibility for an arbitrary commutative ring?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, factoring

Given a commutative ring $R$, we can define a divisibility relation by $a|b$ on the elements of $R$ iff there exists $c \in R$ such that $b = ca$. What are the properties of this relation in general? Is it, like the case of the integers a lattice?

I know for certain cases (e.g. integral domains) this is indeed the case, but what about more general rings? In particular, I am interested in cases where the nilradical of $R$ is non-trivial. In particular, I would like to know in what instances can we say in general that such a preorder is a meet semilattice.

Answer (score 4):

The divisibility poset of a ring $R$ is a lattice iff every pair of elements has a gcd and a lcm.

This does not happen in every commutative ring.

For instance, in the ring $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-5}]$ there is no gcd for $6$ and $2(1+\sqrt{-5})$ (see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/103593/a-question-about-proving-that-there-is-no-greatest-common-divisor)).

A class of rings that have this property is [GCD domains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GCD_domain), which generalize UFDs.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1229945/looking-for-an-example-of-a-gcd-domain-which-is-not-a-ufd.

Comment: Are you aware of if any non-integeral domain examples exist?

Comment: @Sintrastes, not right now.