# Is it always possible to extend a ring to a unital ring?

Tags: ring-theory

Just started learning algebra. So it's defined that ring is the ring not requiring a multiple 1, while unital ring does. Given a ring, is it always possible to extend it to a unital ring?

Comment: See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rng_%28algebra%29#Adjoining_an_identity_element).

Comment: In [many ways,](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/911234/242) some more suitable than the standard Dorroh adjunction (depending on context).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting with a ring $A$ having no multiplicative unit. Consider the direct sum $\mathbb{Z}\oplus A$ with the following addition $(m+\alpha)+(n+\beta)=(m+n)+(\alpha+\beta)$ and multiplication $(m+\alpha).(n+\beta)=mn +m\beta+\alpha n+\alpha\beta$ You can check it is a ring with unit $(1,0)$ and identifying $(0,\alpha)$ with $\alpha$ (and not $(0,\alpha)$ as in previous) makes it an extension of $A$

Comment: It's a little confusing to use both ordered pairs and sums of pairs in your notation. It would probably be best to do what every book does and just use ordered pairs...