# Adjoining $1$ to a ring

Tags: abstract-algebra

Given a ring $R$, show that there exists a ring $R'$ with unity such that $R$ is a subring
(up to isomorphism) of it.

I am not getting the meaning of the question.

Comment: can you please explain how will I show the part upto Isomorphism?

Comment: There are [many ways](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/911234/242) to adjoin $1$, the standard Dorroh extension being the most well known.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\mathbb Z\times R$ be the underlying set of $R'$.

Define addition by: $\langle n,r\rangle+\langle m,s\rangle=\langle n+m,r+s\rangle$.

Define multiplication by $\langle n,r\rangle\langle m,s\rangle=\langle nm,mr+ns+rs\rangle$.

It can be shown that $R'$ is a ring having $\langle1,0\rangle$ as unit.

The map $\phi: R'\rightarrow R$ prescribed by $r\mapsto\langle0,r\rangle$ is an injective ringhomomorphism so that its image is a subring of $R'$ isomorphic with $R$.

Comment: This is the [Dorroh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rng_%28algebra%29#Adjoining_an_identity_element) adjunction of $1$. It is [not always](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/911234/242) the best way to adjoin $1$ since it may not preserve crucial properties.

Comment: @BillDubuque Thank you for the link. New stuff for me. Often when I see comments/answers of you the title of a book - written by someone named J.R.R Tolkien - comes into my mind.