# Adjoining an identity to a ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, noncommutative-algebra

I am run into the following in an Algebra text:

"Let $R_0=\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z⊕\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z⊕\cdots$ viewed as a ring without identity, with addition and multiplication defined componentwise. Let $R=\mathbb Z⊕R_0$ be the ring obtained by "adjoining" an identity $1\in \mathbb Z$ to $R_0$."

My question is:

> What is the identity of $R$?

If it is the pair $(1,0)$ so for any nonzero element $e\in R_0$ we would have $(1,0)(0,e)=(0,e)$ so $(0,0)=(0,e)$ and therefore $e=0$, a contradiction.

Any leading answer would be thanked.

Comment: It's a neat little exercise. What algebra book was it, btw?

Comment: Exercises in Modules and Rings, T.Y.Lam.

Comment: This well-known way to adjoin $1$ is due to Dorroh. [See here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/911234/242) for further discussion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Multiplication is not defined coordinatewise, rather $(n,r)(m,s)=(nm,rs+rm+ns)$. In particular $(1,0)(n,s)=(n,s)$. Writing $(n,r)$ as $n+r$ should help in understanding why we have defined multiplication in such a way.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Now, if $P$ is a prime ideal containing $R_0$ and $e\in R_0$ we know that $e$ is idempotent so $(1-e)e=0$. How could we get that $e=0$? And how could we deduce  that the element $(2,0)\in R$ is not a zero divisor in $R_P$?

Comment: @karparvar Under this operation (which is not the only candidate, but I admit is probably the most likely candidate) $e^2=e$ for *everything* in $R_0$. Why would there be any expectation for $e=0$?

Comment: @rschwieb I meant $e=0\in R_P$. I thought a little and realized that: it is because $e\in P$ whence $1-e$ is not in $P$, so, the equality $(1-e)e=0$ gives $e/1=0$ as an element of $R_P$.

Comment: @karparvar Under this multiplication, $(2,0)(0,x)=0$ for any $x$ in the $R_0$, and hence in any localization. Unless $(0,R_0)$ collapses to zero in the localization, it looks like (2,0) is a zero divisor.

Comment: @karparvar Ah ok, e would definitely be zero in the localization, yes.

Comment: @karparvar that also explains why $(0, R_0)$ does collapse to zero when localizing at any prime containing $R_0$ :)