# Show RxZ is a Ring with 1

Tags: linear-algebra, ring-theory

The problem is:
$R$ is NOT a ring with "1", show that $R'=R\times \mathbb{Z} $ with Addition:   $(r_1,n_1)+(r_2,n_2)=(r_1+r_2,n_1+n_2)$
and Multiplication:
$(r_1,n_1) \cdot (r_2,n_2)=(r_1r_2+n_1r_2+n_2r_1,n_1n_2)$
is a Ring with element "1", and $1=(0,1)$ (the neutral element).
I have shown all the properties of a ring. That is: $(R',+)$ is a commutative group and $(R',\cdot)$ is a semigroup. I still have to show Distributive property, but that should be no problem.
What I find really confusing is to show that my neutral element $1=(0,1)$, because no matter what I do, when I multiply:
$(0,1) \cdot (r_1,n_1)=(0\cdot r_1+1\cdot r_1 + n_1\cdot 0,1\cdot n_1)= (1\cdot r_1,n_1)$ which would be no problem, but the first sentence says R is NOT a ring with "1", so I don't know if I can say that $1\cdot r_1 = r_1$.
I would be grateful if someone could clarify this for me.

Comment: fyi: this was of adjoining $1$ is often credited to **Dorroh** and named as such, e.g. see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/911234/242) for links.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $n\cdot r$ here means *addition* of $r$ with itself $n$ times, where $n\in\Bbb N$, so we get

$$(0,1)(r,n)=(0\cdot r+r+n\cdot 0,\  1\cdot n) =(r, n)$$
And similarly from the right side (if $R$ is not commutative).