# The successor of 0 in an ordered ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, order-theory

### The Setup

I am investigating properties of the following definition of ordered rings:

> Let $R$ be a ring. We say $R$ is an ordered ring under the total order relation $\leq$ if, for all $a,b,c \in R$, $$
> (1). a \leq b \text{ implies } a+c \leq b+c, \text{ and}
> $$ $$(2). 0 \leq a \text{ and } 0\leq b \text{ implies } 0\leq ab.
> $$

We can also say $R$ is strictly ordered by $\leq$ if the above conditions hold with the strict order $<$ replacing $\leq$ throughout. It's been noted on [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3822980/different-definitions-of-ordered-ring) and other places that the two notions of strict/non-strict are separate.

I found and proved the following theorem while looking at the order topology of $R$:

> Let $(R,\leq)$ be a (nonzero) ordered ring with unity. If $0$ has an immediate successor $\epsilon \in R$, then $\epsilon\leq1$, and either $\epsilon^2 = 0$  or $\epsilon^2 = \epsilon$.

The proof is simple: we must have $\epsilon \leq 1$ because otherwise $1 \in (0,\epsilon)$, a contradiction. But then $0 < \epsilon \leq 1$ implies $0 \leq \epsilon^2 \leq \epsilon$ upon multiplication by $\epsilon$.

### The Question

In the theorem, $\mathbb{Z}$ is a simple example of the latter case, because the "$\epsilon$" is just $1$. One can show that this is always so in a discrete strictly ordered ring. I also have an example of the former case: the dual integers $\mathbb{Z}[\epsilon] = \{a+b\epsilon : a,b\in\mathbb{Z}, \epsilon^2 = 0\}$, together with the lexicographic order. Here $\epsilon$ is the immediate successor of zero.

**My question is this: Is there an ordered ring $R$ (necessarily non-strictly ordered) such that $0$ has an immediate successor $\epsilon \in R$ with $\epsilon^2 = \epsilon$ and $\epsilon \neq 1$?**

My intuition tells me that the answer is no, but I don't have any evidence to back it. Any insight is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, it is impossible for an ordered ring to have any element $\epsilon\neq 0,1$ such that $\epsilon^2=\epsilon$.  Note first that $\epsilon(1-2\epsilon)=-\epsilon$ so $1-2\epsilon$ must be negative and thus $\epsilon>1-\epsilon$.  But note that $(1-\epsilon)^2=1-\epsilon$ and $1-\epsilon\neq 0,1$ as well so the same argument applies with $1-\epsilon$ in place of $\epsilon$ to conclude that $1-\epsilon>\epsilon$.  This is a contradiction.

Comment: Thanks! Looking at $\epsilon(1-2\epsilon)$ seems somewhat "magic" to me--is there a more concrete way of arriving there?

Comment: I came up with it by just messing around.  But here's a more natural motivation: it's $\delta-\epsilon$, where $\delta=1-\epsilon$.  The elements $\delta$ and $\epsilon$ are both idempotent with $\epsilon\delta=0$.  The result is that $\epsilon(\delta-\epsilon)=-\epsilon$ whereas $\delta(\delta-\epsilon)=\delta$, so $\delta-\epsilon$ has to be both negative and positive.

Comment: Or for another way to think about it, since $\delta\epsilon=0$, if $0\leq\delta\leq\epsilon$ then $0\leq\delta^2\leq\delta\epsilon=0$ so $\delta^2=0$, and similarly $\epsilon\leq\delta$ would give $\epsilon^2=0$.

Comment: Cool, thanks again! I forgot how important it is to start with combining $\epsilon$ and $1-\epsilon$ when dealing with idempotents