# Can integral domain be trivial? (error in Herstein's Topics in Algebra)

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I am studying Ring Theory from Herstein's book "Topics in algebra" and I would like to discuss one moment.

**Definition 1.** Let $R$ be a ring. The element $a\neq 0\in R$ is called zero-divisor  if there exists $b\neq 0\in R$ such that $ab=0_R$.

**Definition 2.** *An integral domain* is the commutative ring which has not zero-divisors.

Also it is easy prove the following fact: If $D$ is an integral domain of finite characteristics then characteristics is a prime number.

Can trivial ring be an integral domain? If yes then it's characteristics is not prime which contradicts to the above fact!

But Herstein does not say nothing about triviality of integral domain.

Can anyone clarify this question, please?

Comment: I would guess that this is an edge case that Herstein either didn't consider or didn't bother making note of (or possibly that the author doesn't consider the zero ring to be a ring - I had a professor who took that position once, although I don't think it's a great position to take).

Comment: Yea, generally in the definition of integral domain the ring is required to be a ring with unity $1 \neq 0$.

Comment: @wgrenard, Herstein does not require this condition. In his definition it need not to contain unity $1\neq 0$!

Comment: Yea, I see what you mean. I'm just saying I agree with the comment above mine. Because every definition I've ever read requires this. I just double checked in Lang's *Algebra* and it specifies there that $1 \neq 0$.

Comment: You should check to see if Herstein allows the trivial ring to be included in his definition of a ring.

Comment: @wgrenard, But I am working through Herstein's book :) And i would like to know what's wrong with this case?! Unfortunately, Herstein does not say nothing about trivial ring.

Comment: @RFZ It is nearly universal to say that an integral domain has nonzero identity.  If one were to adopt the contrary stance, one would have to reinterpret all theorems mentioning them in other books lest they mistakenly apply a result defined the normal way.  There is no obvious benefit to defining them the contrary way.

Comment: @rschwieb, you suggestion makes sense. But it's quite strange that Herstein did not care about it in his book :/

Comment: @RFZ It's hardly surprising that someone would forget to assert something they take for granted all the time. In fact, it's probably absolutely necessary for society to function that not absolutely every assumption has to be specified!  I'm sure someday someone will ask you if you meant to exclude some edge case that you forgot because it seemed absurd to mention.

Answer (score 3):

Generally when one says characteristic is finite it means characteristic is non-zero number.

Because if you consider zero characteristic as finite case then there many non trivial rings with zero characteristic.

Eg. Ring $\mathbb Z$ has $0$ characteristic.

Comment: Indeed, Herstein gives two definitions of characteristics for integral domain: the first one when it's zero and the other one when it's finite. In other words, you mean that if integral domain $D$ has finite characterics then it should not be trivial, right?

Comment: Yes! That’s what above example shows.

Comment: I know that Ring of Integers has $0$ characteristic. But I can't get why you mention this?

Comment: I mentioned this only to explain when we say finite characteristic it means its non zero finite number.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/98605/why-characteristic-zero-and-not-infinite-characteristic

Comment: Dear Mayuresh L! After some thoughts on your post i would like to ask this question: What is the characteristic of trivial ring?

Comment: I am quoting this from wikipedia,“The only ring with characteristic 1 is the trivial ring, which has only a single element 0 = 1. If a nontrivial ring R does not have any nontrivial zero divisors, then its characteristic is either 0 or prime. In particular, this applies to all fields, to all integral domains, and to all division rings. Any ring of characteristic 0 is infinite”.