# Definition of Characteristic Zero

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Most definitions of [characteristic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_(algebra)) I come across are along the following lines:

> A ring $R$ has characteristic $n\geqslant 1$ if $n$ is the least positive integer satisfying
> $$nx=0$$
> for all $x\in R$, and that $R$ has **characteristic 0 otherwise**.

Now, the definition I recall from my undergraduate study is different: we said that $R$ has characteristic 0 if each non-zero element $x\in R$ satisfies
$nx\neq 0$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$.
In other words, for us, characteristic 0 is equivalent to [torsion-free](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torsion-free_module); so we would say that, e.g.,  $R=(\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z)\times \mathbb Z$ simply does not have a characteristic, since $n(0,1)$ is never $0$, yet $2(1,0)=0$.

Notice that the "usual" (Wikipedia) definition and my definition are in agreement when $R$ is an integral domain, the only time this makes a difference is when $R$ is not an integral domain.

The definition we did is in accordance with that given in the textbook [Topics in Algebra](https://www.wiley.com/en-us/Topics+in+Algebra%2C+2nd+Edition-p-9780471010906) by Herstein, who says that the concept of characteristic for arbitrary rings is meaningless:

[image]

Now, some people argue that the definition I give (which implicitly refrains from assigning a characteristic to rings with torsion elements) is an incorrect one, see for instance [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3661598/301095).

**So, my question is**: why is it useful to say that such rings have characteristic 0, as opposed to leaving the characteristic undefined?

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/98605/why-characteristic-zero-and-not-infinite-characteristic

Comment: Undefined is not our friend in mathematics.

Comment: @lhf That question is quite different to mine, I'm asking why does it make sense to consider the notion of characteristic 0 for rings which are not integral domains.

Comment: It probably doesn't matter all that much. The notion of characteristic is most relevant for distinguishing between very differently behaved fields (esp. the characteristic $0$ versus characteristic $p>0$ distinction). Non-field examples where characteristic is relevant for classifying results will likely be integral domains, in the situation of mixed characteristic: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_of_mixed_characteristic .